There is no sound in Ubuntu 24.04 for XPS 9640, output device is "dummy output"
I have tried:

alsa_base.conf : options snd-hda-intel model=generic
options snd-hda-intel dmic_detect=0

blacklist.conf: blacklist snd_soc_skl


3.**** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices **** card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 3: Generic Digital [Generic Digital] Subdevices: 1/1 Subdevice #0: subdevice #0 card 1: NVidia [HDA NVidia], device 3: HDMI 0 [HDMI 0] Subdevices: 1/1 Subdevice #0: subdevice #0 card 1: NVidia [HDA NVidia], device 7: HDMI 1 [HDMI 1] Subdevices: 1/1 Subdevice #0: subdevice #0 card 1: NVidia [HDA NVidia], device 8: HDMI 2 [HDMI 2] Subdevices: 1/1 Subdevice #0: subdevice #0 card 1: NVidia [HDA NVidia], device 9: HDMI 3 [HDMI 3] Subdevices: 1/1 Subdevice #0: subdevice #0 

when aplay -l | grep HDMI
I see card 1: NVidia [HDA NVidia], device 3: HDMI 0 [HDMI 0] card 1: NVidia [HDA NVidia], device 7: HDMI 1 [HDMI 1] card 1: NVidia [HDA NVidia], device 8: HDMI 2 [HDMI 2] card 1: NVidia [HDA NVidia], device 9: HDMI 3 [HDMI 3]
When I try systemctl --user status pipewire pipewire-session-manager

`Unit pipewire-session-manager.service could not be found.
● pipewire.service - PipeWire Multimedia Service
Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/user/pipewire.service; enabled; preset: e>
Active: active (running) since Sat 2024-05-11 16:10:08 EDT; 19min ago
TriggeredBy: ● pipewire.socket
Main PID: 2516 (pipewire)
Tasks: 3 (limit: 76633)
Memory: 5.7M (peak: 7.1M)
CPU: 258ms
CGroup: /user.slice/user-1000.slice/user@1000.service/session.slice/pipewi>
└─2516 /usr/bin/pipewire
`
Nothing works for me now.

how did you solve this? or was it solved anyway or not?
